# Is there a way to detect when a user has paid for a Google App Marketplace app you published?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We're currently in the process of publishing a Laravel web app to Google App Marketplace and I have read every section of the guides found here https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/overview but there doesn't seem to be any mention of detecting when a user has successfully paid for your app. Because ultimately what we want to achieve is to prevent just anybody from accessing the registration/initial setup page and only grant access to G Suite domains that have paid for the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The G Suite Marketplace does not support payments. If you have implemented your own payment solution then it's up to you to restrict access to paying users.